# How to reverse an address of char pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse

I'm trying to reverse an address of char pointer array, program is working but it doesn't show anything and stopping.

```
void swapArr(char ** arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    char ** temp;   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        *temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[n-i+1];
        arr[n-i+1]=*temp;
    }       
}

void main()
{
.
.
.
      cin>>lenArr;
      char *arr = new char[lenArr];
      swapArr(&arr,lenArr);
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: Since `temp` is uninitialized, using `*temp` is a mistake.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text.  This allows you to use `std::reverse(my_text.begin(), my_text.end();`.

Comment: I want to reverse the address of the arra like 10x0010, 10x0020, 10x0030 to 10x0030, 10x0020, 10x0010

Comment: You need nano bots that swap the wires in your memory.

Comment: Explain again, you don't have valid hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: ok i just want to raplace this address in same array
0x22fe10
0x22fe18
0x22fe20
0x22fe28
0x22fe30

to

0x22fe30
0x22fe28
0x22fe20
0x22fe18
0x22fe10

Answer (score 0):

To swap the contents of an an address in a pointer, you need to swap the contents of the pointer (not what the pointer is pointing to).  This could lead to undefined behavior because you are making the pointer point to some other location.

*Note: the following is untested*

```
char * my_pointer = "Hello";
char * temp_pointer = my_pointer;
cout << "before reversing the pointer: " << static_cast<void *>(temp_pointer) << "\n";
std::reverse(static_cast<uint8_t *>(&my_pointer),
             static_cast<uint8_t *>(&my_pointer) + sizeof(my_pointer));
cout << "after reversing the pointer: " << static_cast<void *>(my_pointer) << endl;
```

**Edit 1: Reversing an array of pointers**
Given:

```
  char * array_of_pointers[25];
```

You could use:

```
  std::reverse(&array_of_pointers[0], &array_of_pointers[25]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate memory for `temp`. Do the following during declaration of `temp` -

```
char ** temp= new char *[(const int) n];
```

However, it's better to use `std::string` in your case if you work in C++.